# Corrigir ou impedir exibição de "Erro de Script"

Tags: javascript, jquery, delphi-xe5, navegador-de-internet

No **Delphi** eu chamo uma página HTML que exibe alguns gráficos feitos com [`jChartFX`](http://www.jchartfx.com/) dentro de um `TWebBrowser`, estão funcionando normalmente, porém ao clicar em qualquer gráfico ele me mostra esse alerta de **Erro de Script**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber se via código tem como eu impedir que esses alertas apareçam ou se existe alguma solução para esse erro especificamente.

Os gráficos estão funcionando corretamente, mas ao clicar em uma barra ou em uma fatia do donut, por exemplo, ele fica mostrando esse alerta e isso é bem chato.

Comment: Testa colocar um `try`/ `catch` à volta da função que chama o gráfico. Mas provavelmente tens mesmo de corrigir no código pois isso é assíncrono em relação à função que chama o gráfico uma vez que espera pelo click.

Comment: Isso é uma configuração do browser (internet explorer), e que eu saiba já faz uns anos que ela vem desligada por padrão. Deve estar habilitada na sua máquina por ser um ambiente de desenvolvimento. Seja como for, concordo com o @Sergio, o caminho é evitar o erro, e não tentar esconder a mensagem.

Answer (score 2):

Verifica se existe alguma ocorrência em que o objecto é **undefined** ou um outro tipo de objecto que não seja suportado pelos métodos que estás a tentar usar. Faz **console.logs** do objecto, usa o JSON.stringify se for preciso para verificares isso.

Outra coisa que poderia ser, é ter a certeza que o objecto onde estás a fazer click é realmente criado antes de o tentares usar. Costuma ser um erro bastante comum e que por vezes deixamos passar.

Comment: Por incrível que pareça era só um problema de *case sensitive*. a função estava sendo chamada como **bI** e na verdade era **bi** rs

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Era problema de *case sensitive*.
Olhei no console e tava mostrando:

> TypeError: "bI" is not a function

Dai olhei o link `Leia mais` que ele mostra e lá dizia que pode acontecer por problema de `case sensitive`. Fiz uma busca no código e vi que na linha informada a função na verdade era `bi` e não `bI`.